# Center text in footer with google doc extension script

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is my code. The family and size work but it doesn't center.

```
function styleFooter() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var foot = body.getFooter();
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Helvetica Neue';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 9;
  foot.setAttributes(style);  
}
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more info and can you format better your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need to `getParagraphs()` and iterate each paragraph of the footer. Try this, it worked for me:

```
function styleFooter() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var foot = body.getFooter().getParagraphs(); // gets a list of your footer paragraphs
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Helvetica Neue';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 9;

  // iterates each of your footer paragraphs
  foot.forEach(function(element) {
    element.setAttributes(style); 
  })
}
```

From the Google Docs [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/horizontal-rule):

> A HorizontalRule can be contained within a ListItem or Paragraph, but cannot itself contain any other element.

Comment: This doesn't work in the footer. The error thrown says: Cannot find function forEach in object FooterSection.

Comment: Please, see line 3 of the code in my answer. You may have forgotten  to add `.getParagraphs()`